# Missing Vector from the std:: list

Tags: arrays, vector, codeblocks

I type std:: but the vector entry does is not on the list. Is there any library that still needs to be included? I only have `#include <iostream>`.

I'm using Codeblocks 10.05 and the compiler is GCC 4.4.1. I'm told arrays can't be resized so my only option is a vector. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need,

```
#include <vector>
```